# How remain jdom service symbol from ouput

Tags: java, parsing, jdom

Hello I am have this code

```
   Document rootElement = saxBuilder.build(inputXML);
        Element element = rootElement.getRootElement();

        Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        Element e = element.getChild("Body", ns);

        Format format=Format.getCompactFormat();

        List listAttributrBody = e.getChildren();
        String element2 = listAttributrBody.get(0).toString();
        System.out.print(element2);
        InputStream propfile = new                 


    FileInputStream("/home/igor/IdeaProjects/jdomtest/src/main/resources/properties.xml");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(propfile);
        String pathToOutput=properties.getProperty(element2);
        //System.out.println(pathToOutput);
```

And it's ouput like this:

```
 [Element: <Action__CompIntfc__CIName/>]
```

but I am need only clear Action_*CompIntfc*_CIName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the xml tag name you have to change this:

```
   List listAttributrBody = e.getChildren();
   String element2 = listAttributrBody.get(0).toString();
```

To this:

```
    List<Element> listAttributrBody = e.getChildren();
    String element2 = listAttributrBody.get(0).getName();
```

If you are using older version (1.1) you are not allowed to use generics () then you have to do this:

```
   List listAttributrBody = e.getChildren();
   Element el2 = (Element)listAttributrBody.get(0);
   String element2 = el2.getName();
```

You can read more about available methods in
[jdom api](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Element.html)

Comment: But I cant replace it, because getName() in this object not supported

Comment: Which jdom version are you using? I just noticed that you are not using generics and probably you are trying to access that property on the Object rather than on the Element. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am update maven depedency on jdom2 and your solution is working.